# Determine which the link is hashtag

Tags: jquery, gallery, hashtag

I'm a beginner with using jQuery and am experiencing a question.

I made a gallery and the gallery links are added to facilitate the hashtags user. For example, if you add a favorite link, to access the page will see the right image, because the hash tag is present in the link.

The gallery is almost working, actually I just wanted to add a class to make the selected image set.

```
$gallery = window.location.hash;

//If have no hashtag, adds the class on the first image
if( $gallery == '')
    jQuery('.gallery-nav ul li').children('a').first().addClass('current');
else
{
    jQuery('.gallery-nav ul li').each(function($i){
        $link_hash = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');

        if( $link_hash == $gallery)
        {
            alert ( $link_hash );
        }
    });
}
```

Until the first part, "If have no hashtag, adds the class on the first image" is working right, but then I do not know how. For example, if the the link is: http://example.net/gallery.php#3, I want to add the class on the third link.

In the above function, it shows the alert correctly. When it reaches the selected link it shows the alert. But I do not know how to add the class in the link.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: FYI - For questions like this that it involve DOM selection, it is always a good idea to provide a sample of the HTML that is being selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just select that element directly using the [`attribute-ends-with-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to choose the element where the `href` ends with the value of `$gallery`. *(I assume there are fewer than ten.)*

As you can see, the `$gallery` is concatenated into the selector string.

```
else {
    jQuery('.gallery-nav ul li a[href$=' + $gallery + ']').addClass('current');
}
```